# Extract decimal number from a string using only loops

Tags: java, php

I was wondering - is there a way to extract a decimal (float/double) number from a string, but with no regex or functions - just loops ?

f.e.

```
$str = "weiun.fqw7pofnj89.5poopf99"
```

so it should be '89.5' - but I cant manage to do it manually - any ideas ?

Comment: If you can't use the proper tool then it's just homework.

Comment: I saw that question on some board and tried it myself - with no luck - so it confused me

Comment: what do You mean Andreas ?

Comment: `but with no regex or functions`, what do you mean by functions?

Comment: without any is_number() getval() etc - just using loops

Comment: I got stuck here: https://3v4l.org/0CYhX and now I need to go to bed. My plan is to use $pos to remember the positions of numbers or dots and if the next one is not a number or dot clear the memory of pos. Num is supposed to be the float.

Comment: Nice. It's so freackin hard - but remember not to use any 'is_numeric' !

Comment: @tryboon4 so if is_numeric is a function, isn't `if()` also a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code with out using any functions or regex.

```
$string = "weiun.fqw7pofnj89.5poopf99";
// find the length of the string
$length = strlen($string);
// loop the string
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
  // find the '.'
  if($string[$i] == '.'){
    $number_before_decimal ='';
    $number_after_decimal ='';
    // backward loop until we find non numeric value
    for($j=($i-1);$j>=0;$j--){
        if((ord($string[$j])>=48) && (ord($string[$j])<=57)){
           // add values in reverse
           $number_before_decimal = $string[$j].$number_before_decimal;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    // forward loop until we find non numeric value
    for($k=$i;$k<$length;$k++){
        if($string[$k] == '.') continue;
        if((ord($string[$k])>=48) && (ord($string[$k])<=57)){
             $number_after_decimal .= $string[$k];
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    if(($number_before_decimal!='') && ($number_after_decimal!='')){
        echo $number_before_decimal.'.'.$number_after_decimal;
        echo "<br/>";
    }
  }
}
```

Out put:

```
89.5
```

It works to fetch multiple decimal values in the given string

```
$string = "weiun2.3m2.5o0.6fqw7pofnj89.5poopf99";
```

Output:
    2.3
2.5
0.6
89.5

Comment: @Jaumzera Thank you

Comment: @tryboon4 yes it is

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$str = "weiun.fqw7pofnj89.5poopf99";
$numbers = "";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    if(($str[$i] >= "0" && $str[$i] <= "9") || $str[$i] == ".") {
        $numbers .= $str[$i];
    }
}

echo $numbers;
?>
```

But the output float number will be `.789.599`, once you have these values in your original string.

Comment: @tryboon4 Why can't you use regex?

Comment: because I was just curious is it possible

Comment: Regex itself does it without regex.